# PRISM: Region is not register with the RegionManager

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a custom control, which derives from User Control.

```
public class CustomControl : ContentControl 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualCompareControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VisualCompareControl", typeof (FrameworkElement), typeof (CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement)));
    public FrameworkElement VisualCompareControl
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement) GetValue(VisualCompareControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VisualCompareControlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

This is my 'View':

```
<myNameSpace:CustomControl>
    <VisualCompareControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MyRegion" />
</myNameSpace:CustomControl>
```

Navigating and injecting a View into this region is done the standard way:

```
RegionManager.RequestNavigate("MyRegion", navigation, navigationParameter);
```

When I debug the region 'MyRegion', is not registered within the `RegionManager`. How come? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare the region through a control with a region adapter declared. I assume your `VisualCompareControl` control of type `FrameworkElement` doesn't have one.

You can [create a custom region adapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921129.aspx) for it or use one of the three controls with out of the box Prism adapters: `ContentControl`, `ItemsControl` or `Selector` derived controls.

Since `CustomControl` derives `ContentControl` you could try:

```
<myNameSpace:CustomControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MyRegion" />
```

Or you could go for `ContentControl` directly:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MyRegion" />
```